# How to add user to file permission in Windows Server 2008 R2 with Commad Line

Tags: php, windows, permissions, exec, windows-server-2008

We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 with Plesk. Our website is developed with Php CodeIgniter framework.

We can't read file from subdomain which is uploaded, need to set main domain username to uploaded file, so I can do it with manual but we need to do this with command line so we can exec in Php.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, here you go ;)

```
$file_url = "C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\sub.domain.com\uploads\image.jpg";
$group_username = "example_username";
exec('icacls '.$file_url.' /grant '.$group_username.':f ');
```

Raw version:

```
exec("icacls C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\sub.domain.com\image.jpg /grant example_username:f");
```

That's it. This code will give **Full Control**.

See more; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls

Drop a like if it's useful :)